# Log4j2 XML is not getting class path

Tags: java, xml, log4j, classpath

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="MSIFatalFile" fileName="Fatal.log" 
            filePattern="Fatal-%i.log">
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{ISO8601}] %-5level %logger{6} - %msg%n"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="MSIErrorFile" fileName="Error.log" 
            filePattern="Error-%i.log">
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{ISO8601}] %-5level %logger{6} - %msg%n"/>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="MISFile" fileName="MIS.log" 
            filePattern="MIS-%i.log">
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%d{ISO8601}] %-5level %logger{6} - %msg%n"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <loggers>
        <logger name="fatalLogger" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="MSIFatalFile" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="errorLogger" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="MSIErrorFile" />
        </logger>

        <logger name="misLogger" level="ALL" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="MISFile" />
        </logger>

    </loggers>

</configuration>
```

when i put this at my source level it works fine, but when i changes it external directory folder that it is not resolved and file are not updating even not creating when creating logger instances.

I set the clsspath of all jar and xml directory by `System.setProprty("java.class.path", path)`

but it did't work. pls suggest what i am doing wrong here.

**Update** tried all possible way but not able to set classpath of(or reference file it more approprate i think) xml file residing at external folder. The problem is that the enviornment that it getting when i place it at project level how would it get when i place it at external folder.

Comment: Set your `external directory` into class path.

Comment: @CycDemo How to do it programmatically, i did it by System.setProprty("java.class.path", path) and UrlClassLoader but it not works. As I am putting this in a external folder and it is not getting refreced. and when i put it in my project level it is getting refrenced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMConfigurator.configure("log4j.xml")` to load configuration file

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit) of log4j (1). Use the `log4j.configuration` system property to specify the initilization file and set the `log4j.debug` system property to get some more log4j debug output. You will find information about the log4j initialization phase in that output.

E.g.:

```
java -cp C:\myApp\lib\*; -Dlog4j.configuration=C:\myApp\etc\log4j.xml -Dlog4j.debug MyMainClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the xml wherever it is.
can use System.setProperty("log4j.configuration", xmlpath).

this works in my case.